# Vuejs how to force css inline display in html loop

Tags: css, vue.js

Hi everyone I'm having trouble concerning css and I'm not quite sure where the problem is really coming from.

I have three templates dynamically generated:

```
<div v-html="modelFirst(key, info)" v-for="(info, key) in infos.info"
               :key="key.id"
               class="info"
               style="display:flex;margin-right:5px;line-height:20px;"> 
 </div>
```

v-html containing :

```
modelFirst(key, info){
        const label = key > 2 ? `<label style="font-weight:bold;display:inline-block;">${info.label} </label>`: ``;
        const color = key == 2 ? `color: #CCCBD0` : ``;
        const bold = key <= 2 ? `font-weight: bold` : ``;
        const space = key <=2 ? `margin-bottom: 10px`: ``;
        return this.model = `<div display:flex;>${label}

                                <div style="
                                            ${space};
                                            ${color};
                                            ${bold};">${info.text}</div>
                              </div>`;

      },
```

I'm using litteral templates for specifics reasons.
It gives me this result :

```
fanto
fanto
myJob
Adresse: 00 street of nowhere 00000
Tel:  01 00 00 00 00
Mobile:  06 00 00 00 00
Email:  fanto@fanto.com
Site:  www.google.fr
```

So labels and divs are aligned as I want but for the 3 datas without labels, it's impossible to get them aligned ! I've tried all the display, flex etc. but nothing's doing anything, I came with a theory that it may be caused by the loop, so how can I force the alignment ?

Comment: Why dont you use a table to align your output?

Comment: Maybe remove the second display flex in your v-html   (return this.model = `<div display:flex;>${label}) , and change it by =   flex-direction:row!important ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you must use `v-html` here where an ordinary Vue template wouldn't work? I see you're got `${info.label}` within the HTML string which could lead to XSS attacks if `info.label` isn't sanitized.